# PHP Sendmail queue priority

Tags: php, linux, sendmail

How can I set message priority in Sendmail queue?

I want all messages from PHP to be served first while I'm sending large news-list to subscribers "in background". Without priority definition urgent messages stuck in queue for a long time.

Comment: Actually resolved it myself before posting the question :) So I attached answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special "Precedence" mail header.

There are several predefined message classes: first-class, special-delivery, list, bulk, junk. *First-class* has the highest priority and *junk* has the lowest.

Other factors are message size and number of recipients.

priority = msgsize - (class * ClassFactor) + (nrcpt * RecipientFactor)

The lower is message *priority*, the faster it will be sent. *ClassFactor* and *RecipientFactor* are weights of these factors. You can change weights and classes in Sendmail config.

```php
/* Low-priority mail */
$to      = 'customer@example.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Precedence: bulk';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: It will make insufficient difference without changing sendmail's default "develivery mode". Default "background" delivery mode forks background process to deliver every message "at once". What you described in default configuration makes difference starting from SECOND delivery attempt.